# R: eBay OAuth - Client Credentials Grant Request

Tags: r, post, oauth-2.0, ebay-api, httr

I'm trying to get my head around OAuth, and decided to play around with the eBay API. While following their [instructions](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html#configure) to get an Application access token, I'm getting a *400 error*.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

# OAuth credentials
client_id <- "x"
client_secret <- "x"
# Required - https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-base64-credentials.html
encod_oauth <- base64_enc(paste0(client_id, ":", client_secret))

auth_token_res <- 
  POST("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token",
       add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   Authorization = paste0("Basic ", encod_oauth)),
       body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials", 
                   scope = urlEncode("https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope", reserved = T)))
```

Examining the content, this is apparently to do with the *grant_type* in the body.

```
content(auth_token_res)
$error_description
[1] "grant type in request is not supported by the authorization server"
```

What is wrong with the body request and why?

Comment: Tried both with no luck, thanks.

Comment: `content(auth_token_res)` throws out the same error.

Comment: Tried cURL too, and got an error: `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"request is missing a required parameter or malformed."}(base)`. Think contacting support might be for the best.

Comment: maybe the API manual was not updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it took one and a half hour but i did. you can find code below, written with R. Have nice day. I hope this will be the solution.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(base64enc)

rm(list=ls()) # delete memory
code <- base64encode(charToRaw("TT"));

#getting data from api 
resp <- POST("https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token",
             query = list(grant_type="client_credentials",scope="https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope"),
            add_headers(`Content-Type`='application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        `Authorization`=paste("Basic",code, sep=" ")))

if (http_type(resp) != "application/json") {
  stop("API did not return json", call. = FALSE)
}
parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(resp, "text",encoding = "UTF-8"), simplifyVector = TRUE)
parsed_v2 <- parsed[["response"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving here a working example. It is very difficult to do this but i did.
First i am getting app access token then i am using it to a search api. It is node.js code.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require("querystring");
//The client credentials grant flow
//https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html

axios("https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from(
            //App ID (Client ID):
            `your id and secret key here with : seperated`
        ).toString('base64')
    },
    data: qs.stringify({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        scope: "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope",
        // parsed from redirect URI after returning from eBay,

    })
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Application data");
        console.log(response.data.access_token);

        axios("https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + response.data.access_token
            },
            params: {
                category_ids: "108765",
                q: "Beatles"
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                // console.log(res.data);
                res.data.itemSummaries.map((e) => console.log(e.title));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("**************Get search error**************")
                console.log(err)
            });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("**************Get access token error**************")
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Comment: ı had a problem about user access token. If you have solved that and get user access token. We will work together. It is very disturbing process.

Comment: Can't really marked this as complete because I was looking for an R answer. In saying that, there's very little in any language on here, so hopefully this is useful to somebody else.

Comment: If i will have time i will do it with R and share from here. You are right to look an R solution. It is better. Actually when i was writing this solution, i thought nobody reply or look 5 months ago s question :) I was looking for a user access token solution and saw this issue has not been replied by anybody. I wanted to write.